# Ubuntu Core - Startup Interactive Script

Tags: boot, command-line, scripts

I have a fully supported device which I boot using an Ubuntu 22 Desktop image and "Try" it.

Then I run the xzcat / dd commands to flash Ubuntu Core 22 onto the disk.

Then I restart the machine and boot with the disk into Ubuntu Core 22.

Questions:
How do I run a startup script on Ubuntu Core that will ALLOW interactivity by the user to type something in using the keyboard?
(My script has a few "read"s in it)

I understand I will have to modify the image and do the whole signing certificate thing which is fine - I JUST need to know the commands or what changes I need to make so that a script is run automatically along with being interactable please.

Thank you!

Pasha

Comment: Do you want your script to run during the first boot only? Will it affect the system provisioning and setup? Or do you want your script to run only during during subsequent boots (**not** the first boot), when setup is already complete and the server is operating? What does the interactive script accomplish?

Comment: Hi,
I want the script to run on first boot after flash (when it restarts after ubuntu desktop flashes core onto the disk)

That is when a human will be there, ready to interact with a keyboard.

So I want that script to run (it basically installs 2 snaps and sets the hostname to whatever the human would type in).

After that it can just run stand-alone.

The script simply asks the user to enter a 4 digit code that it then sets the hostname to... and does 1 line of "snap set" with the same code.

Frankly, the human can manually run the script too - just need interactivity with keyb

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1499245/edit) to add this information.